# How do I get a signal once when I click

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a build system but when I click, it spawns multiple parts.

```
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")

uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
-- code
end
end)
```

Comment: This code looks fine and when I test it it only fires once per click. If you add `print` statements, is the InputBegan function firing twice per click? Your problem is likely somewhere else. Do you have multiple copies of this LocalScript kicking around?

Comment: My bad, I used a loop and put it inside it

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is alright, there's nothing wrong with it.

```lua
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")

uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
    -- code
    end
end)
```

Consider checking if the event is only defined once; avoid binding the event in a loop to prevent memory leaks.